# How to dynamically create a TypeScript table in POWER BI

Tags: typescript, powerbi

Using d3 and typeScript is not that hard from html ...

Example which i have created --

```
<table id="view">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

TypeScript

```
// the table rows, typically loaded from data file using d3.csv
    var hours = [
        { title: "Fredrik", one: 8, two: 5, three: 6, four: 9, five: 5, six: 8, seven: 8, eight: 0, nine: 8, ten: 12 },
        { title: "Yoakim", one: 4, two: 6, three: 8, four: 3, five: 8, six: 4, seven: 2, eight: 1, nine: 7, ten: 10  },
        { title: "Lars", one: 8, two: 12, three: 6, four: 8, five: 5, six: 8, seven: 8, eight: 10, nine: 8, ten: 13  },
    ];

    // column definitions
    var columns = [
        { head: 'UserName', cl: 'title', html: ƒ('title') },
        { head: 'one', cl: 'center', html: ƒ('one') },
        { head: 'two', cl: 'center', html: ƒ('two', two()) },
        { head: 'three', cl: 'num', html: ƒ('three', d3.format('$,')) },
        { head: 'four', cl: 'num', html: ƒ('four', d3.format('.1f')) },
        { head: 'five', cl: 'num', html: ƒ('five', d3.format('$,')) },
        { head: 'six', cl: 'num', html: ƒ('six', d3.format('.1f')) },
        { head: 'seven', cl: 'num', html: ƒ('seven', d3.format('$,')) },
        { head: 'eight', cl: 'num', html: ƒ('eight', d3.format('.1f')) },
        { head: 'nine', cl: 'num', html: ƒ('nine', d3.format('$,')) },
        { head: 'ten', cl: 'num', html: ƒ('ten', d3.format('.1f')) }
    ];

    // create table
    var table = d3.select('body')
        .append('table');

    // create table header
    table.append('thead').append('tr')
        .selectAll('th')
        .data(columns).enter()
        .append('th')
        .attr('class', ƒ('cl'))
        .text(ƒ('head'));

    // create table body
    table.append('tbody')
        .selectAll('tr')
        .data(hours).enter()
        .append('tr')
        .selectAll('td')
        .data(function(row, i) {
            return columns.map(function(c) {
                // compute cell values for this specific row
                var cell = {};
                d3.keys(c).forEach(function(k) {
                    cell[k] = typeof c[k] == 'function' ? c[k](row,i) : c[k];
                });
                return cell;
            });
        }).enter()
        .append('td')
        .html(ƒ('html'))
        .attr('class', ƒ('cl'));

    function two() {
        var fmt = d3.format('02d');
        return function(l) { return Math.floor(l / 60) + ':' + fmt(l % 60) + ''; };
    }
```

CSS

```
    <style type="text/css">
    view, td, th {
  height:50;
}

th {
 background-color:black;
  color:white  
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color:#ccc;
  width:200px;
  text-align: center;

}
    </style>
```

Here is the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/christoferhansen/dpuk9n55/1/

Now my question is how can i use the same structure in the Power BI envirnment and get the similar kind of result !

Any one knows any answer of this problem !

Comment: Sharing some of the code you tried, and maybe a sample of your data would help. :)

Comment: This question is too broad. It's not clear what a 'dynamic table' is or what it means to 'dynamically create a TypeScript table'. As toskv mentions if you provide a sample or example of what you're trying to achieve, we might be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @LukaszP. have updated the question

Comment: @toskv updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would recommend you take a look at the default visual that loads within the [Power BI dev tools](https://app.powerbi.com/devtools). Just press "Compile and run" to see it when it loads. It implements a table over a data set in Power BI and you'll see the code structure and what's required.  You'll need to register for [Power BI](https://www.powerbi.com) to access to power bi.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but in the dev tools there is no debugger available, so it is impossible to see what i am doing wrong, that is why i wanted to work in the Visual studio, but there i can not see my plugin list name ...

Comment: here is the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34993944/uncomment-it-to-see-your-plugin-in-powerbivisualsplayground-plugins

Comment: In the browser you should use the built-in browser debugger.  Best way to do that is to stick the statement "debugger;" in your init function.  Then press F12 (most browsers will launch their debugger).  When you press 'compile + run', the debugger will break on your init function.  Same thing works after you export your visual and you want to test it in the Power BI web UI.  Personally, I like this better than debugging in VS, but might be personal preference.