# uncomment it to see your plugin in "powerbivisualsplayground" plugins

Tags: powerbi

How Can i see my plugin in "PowerBIVisualsPlayground" plugins list !

So when i create a iVisual it created some default code where on the plugin list it says `uncomment it to see your plugin in "powerbivisualsplayground" plugins`

So i followed it  and uncomment the code ---

```
i have created a IVisual i the PowerBI visual ---
/* creating ivisualplugin that is used to represent ivisual. */

 //uncomment it to see your plugin in "powerbivisualsplayground" plugins list
 //remember to finally move it to plugins.ts

module powerbi.visuals.plugins {
    export var newvisual: ivisualplugin = {
        name: 'newvisual',
        capabilities: newvisual.capabilities,
        create: () => new newvisual()
    };
}
```

i have uncommented the default code to see my Visual name list o the PowerBI Plugin list but still i can not see my plugin name in the PowerBIVisualsPlayground" plugins list.

I have also tried to move my code to plugins.ts but still no result !!

```
export var newvisual: ivisualplugin = {
    name: 'newvisual',
    watermarkKey: 'newvisual',
    capabilities: newvisual.capabilities,
    create: () => new newvisual()
};
```

Do anyone knows what i am doing wrong !

So my question is again

```
**How can i see my plugin name in the PowerBI Visual plugin List !**
```

Any kind of advice or help will be really appreciable ! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

there are couple of error in your code.

in the first line `ivisualplugin` it Should be `IVisualPlugin`

Change your class and  capabilities name from `newvisual` to `Newvisual`

So the answer is :

```
export var newvisual: IVisualPlugin = {
    name: 'newvisual',
    capabilities: Newvisual.capabilities,
    create: () => new Newvisual()
};
```

Hope it will help you.